# Using Google Cloud Speech API in C# Windows forms

Tags: c#, forms, api, speech, google-speech-api

Since I'm pretty new to using an API in my C# projects, and after a month of unsuccessful attempts I manage to run a simple speech-to-text code in the cloud, but can't do it on my local Visual Studio. I am using the [Cloud Speech-to-Text Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries) from Google but am unable to determine what missing steps I need to complete to be able to use the API in Visual Studio while developing my Windows Forms C# project.  My code is available for [download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kbjEf36MwJ5-31mpAT6yw34Kn9Qbt24E/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Have you read [Cloud Speech-to-Text Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries)?

Comment: Yes, I did. And I think I did everything correctly. There is just no output when I run my application locally.

Comment: If you need assistance debugging/troubleshooting your code, it would be helpful to post the code here, or link to a shared code repository.

Comment: This is the code that I'm using from the tutorial I'm following : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kbjEf36MwJ5-31mpAT6yw34Kn9Qbt24E/view?usp=sharing . I hope you can see the mistake, or at least what I am missing

Comment: @willman could you please see the link?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I assume you have already [created a service account key](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey?_ga=2.16589502.964370804.1583350764-1335316075.1580942041) and you've set your system environment variable `setx GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\full_local_path_to_your_account_key.json"`?

Comment: Let me suggest a few things. 1) Create a new dotnet console project: `dotnet new console`. 2) Replace the program.cs file with the code from the example in your link. 3) Follow the example steps for the service account and audio file. 4) Run the code: `dotnet run`. 5) Rewrite your question and show everything you did, the code and all messages/errors. 6) Once you have the example working you can load the project into Visual Studio and continue developing.

Comment: I think I've set the SA key, but when I check it just says GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and no more info. Could you @willman somehow guide me through the process of setting it up in VS? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: As long as you've set the environment variable on your machine, the API running on your machine will use that Key.  I know the documentation at Google says to use `set` to set the environment variable, but that only sets it temporarily for your current session, to set it permanently on your machine use `setx` at a command prompt, as in `C:\> setx GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\full_local_path_to_your_account_key.json"`

Comment: So I  just managed to use the API to transcribe a prerecorded audio file! the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1khM4V5VBvs7p75bqTeIHiB7VPMTl33h9/view?usp=sharing  . My next question is how to use the API to get input from my microphone. This is the code I was using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o5yMiwD5lS7I29Im0h7SL9AQearAI0IX/view?usp=sharing . But it  does  not seem to work. @willman

Comment: @willman Could you please check out my code and point out my mistakes?

Comment: Could you take a look? @willman